# how to implement joi validator using node js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, joi

I tried crud operation using nodejs and mongodb. It is working fine but how to validate data using joi validator.I do not  know how to add joi validation code in node js connecting mongodb.

product.js

```
const Joi = require('joi');
 router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    (async function() {
        try {
          await client.connect();
          console.log("Connected correctly to server");
          const db = client.db('olc_prod_db');

          let r = await db.collection('Ecommerce').insertOne(req.body);
          assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);
          res.send("Inserted Sucessfully")
          client.close();
        } catch(err) {
          console.log(err.stack);
        }
      })();

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of validating express request body:

```
const Joi = require('joi');

const validateRequest = (schema) => async (req, res, next) => {
    const { error } = Joi.validate(req.body, schema);

    if (error) {  
      throw new Error(error);
    }

    return next();
  };

const validatinSchema =  Joi.object().keys({
    firstName:  Joi.string().required(),
    lastName: Joi.string().required(),
  }),

router.post('/', validateRequest(validationSchema), async (req, res) =>
 // rest of your code
```

Comment: Can you give me for how to add joi code in my code can you give me suggestion.

Comment: Please look closely at the code I provided there is `router.post('/', validateRequest(validationSchema), async (req, res) =>
 // rest of your code goes here`

Comment: I have one more doubt also .I tried to get the data in mongodb using node js.but I got only one data.its throwing error for Can't set headers after they are sent.I tried many ways .but I still facting this issue.how to solve this issue any suggestion

Comment: my db code 
let r = await db.collection('Ecommerce').find();
          r.forEach(function(result,err)
          {
            res.send(result)
          })

Comment: could you create a new question with code and error stack and then give me the link to new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55812098/i-tried-crud-operation-using-nodejs-and-mongodb-all-crud-operation-is-working-f