# I tried crud operation using nodejs and mongodb. all crud operation is working fine.but get method showing only one data not showing all data

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream, nodejs-server

I tried crud Operation using node js and mongodb.all crud operation working fine.but i tried to run get method its showing on;y one record.after i see my code its throwing error (Can't set headers after they are sent).How to solve this issue any one give suggestion.

index.js

```
router.get('/', async (req, res,next) => {
    (async function() {
        try {
          await client.connect();
          console.log("Connected correctly to server");
          const db = client.db('olc_prod_db');
          let r = await db.collection('Ecommerce').find();
          r.forEach(function(result,err)
          {
            res.send(result)
          })
          // Close connection
          client.close();
        } catch(err) {
          console.log(err.stack);
        }
      })();

  });
```

Comment: and also try to console.log(r) before sending it, so make sure the data is fetched from db correctly

Comment: Just remove the loop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
router.get('/', async (req, res,next) => {
(async function() {
    try {
      await client.connect();
      console.log("Connected correctly to server");
      const db = db.collection('Ecommerce').find({}).toArray(function(error, documents) {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send(documents);
      });
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err.stack);
    }
  })();
```

});

For each subsequent request, you have to 'send' once only. This method just completes the request cycle so you can't call it on loop because of loop run 'n' time.

Comment: I tried this type code but its still facing issue(TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON)

Comment: so you have to make a serializer which helps you out for the serialization. also, you can loop through the variable and construct an object which you can further return with the help of `res.send(yourObj);`.

Comment: Can please give some code .I cant understand for this code(res.send(yourObj);)

Comment: Sorry  Nitesh Shaw.I cant add toarray() function in my add code.i tried to add its working fine .Thank you

Comment: help others as well @smithhari

Answer (score 1):

No need in `forEach`, just do:

```
const r = await db.collection('Ecommerce').find({}).toArray();
res.send({ data: r })
```

Comment: this also I already tried it but its showing this type of error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: i tried to console.log(r).but its not showing  db data

Comment: so the problem is not with `res.send`

Comment: but its throwing error for(TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON).How to convert  circular structure to JSON

Comment: I added in my code but still i facing this issue for((TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON)).

Comment: please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370487/node-js-mongodb-driver-async-await-queries

Comment: Thank you @HHilarion Galushka .its working fine,I add my code only .toArray().its worked.